# Running Fire Dynamics Simulator/Smokeview on Latest Ubuntu LTS

Tags: command-line

I am trying to run a program called Fire Dynamics Simulator (FDS/SMV) on the latest version of Ubuntu LTS (20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64).  The program installs via an .sh file package through Terminal and I followed the instructions from the website (here: https://github.com/firemodels/fds/wiki/Installing-and-Running-FDS-on-a-Linux-Cluster).  The Terminal installation process goes through prompts and finishes.  However, when I type in the "fds" command in Terminal to check if it is installed correctly, I get an error that the command does not exist.  Also, the program does not work correctly when calling it to run as instructed.

I'm certain the issue is that it is not installed correctly.  I am using the latest version of the FDS program released for Linux in Aug 21 2020.  Perhaps I need an older version of Ubuntu?  Or a different Linux OS type?  I am new to Ubuntu and Linux but I have used it before and I use the program on Windows in Command Prompt so I am familiar with how to run it and what the commands and results should look like.

The program does not have a version of Linux it is compatible with listed.  The download is here: https://pages.nist.gov/fds-smv/downloads.html.

I am certain Ubuntu is installed correctly.

Anyone with knowledge of this program NIST Fire Dynamics Simulator/Smokeview or installing programs like it that do scientific/mathematical modeling on Ubuntu would be greatly appreciated.

If I do not find a solution, my next guess is to install the version of Ubuntu released before the programs release date, but I am concerned about outdated OS installs.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The instructions mention 2 methods for setting up the environment, one using modules and one without. Which one did you use? (environment modules aren't installed by default in Ubuntu, but there is an optional package to support them). If you edited your .bashrc file, did you source it afterwards (or open a new shell)?

Comment: @steeldriver I used the method without modules.  As I understood, the method for modules was for using or replacing an older version of the program.  I am using a fresh, default install of Ubuntu without environment modules and a new install of the FDS program.  I have not edited the .bashrc file.  Do you think this is something I need to do?  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Did you run `source $HOME/FDS/FDS6/bin/FDS6VARS.sh` and `source $HOME/FDS/FDS6/bin/SMV6VARS.sh` in the terminal before trying to run `fds` ? (noting *"change the paths accordingly to match where you actually installed FDS"*)

Comment: @steeldriver I made the files executable by typing `chmod +x /home/FDS/FDS6/bin/FDS6VARS.sh` and then ran using the command `home/FDS/FDS6/bin/FDSVARS.sh` but I just got no output and the command prompt again.  (I did change to my filepath like you said)

Comment: Getting no output is fine - I don't know what's in the files (since downloading the software requires registration) however they likely just set some environment varibles - hopefully including adding the location of `fds` to your executable search path. Did you try it?

Comment: @steeldriver I tried the command that is supposed to return a install confirmation by typing `fds` in any filepath but got the same error.

Comment: @steeldriver I was typing the wrong command.  I tried `source $HOME/FDS/FDS6/bin/FDS6VARS.sh` exactly and then `which fds`, followed by `fds` and I get the correct output now.  `which fds` was just to check I was in the correct filepath. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was typing the wrong command.  Need to type:

`source $HOME/FDS/FDS6/bin/FDS6VARS.sh` and
`source $HOME/FDS/FDS6/bin/FDS6VARS.sh`

to put FDS in the correct filepath (assuming you installed to default filepath, change the filepath if you did not).  You can add both these commands to `~/.bashrc` file to load FDS to every Terminal window.

These instructions are in the Wiki here: https://github.com/firemodels/fds/wiki/Installing-and-Running-FDS-on-a-Linux-Cluster , after step 4.  I followed the instructions for "if you do not have modules".

Type `which fds` to confirm it is in the correct filepath.